# Add image to window with SDL — c++

Tags: c++, xcode, sdl

I want to add an image to a window. This is my code:

```
SDL_Surface* bitmap = SDL_LoadBMP("bat.bmp");

// Part of the bitmap that we want to draw
SDL_Rect source;
source.x = 24;
source.y = 63;
source.w = 65;
source.h = 44;

// Part of the screen we want to draw the sprite to
SDL_Rect destination;
destination.x = 100;
destination.y = 100;
destination.w = 65;
destination.h = 44;

SDL_Event event;
bool gameRunning = true;

while (gameRunning)
{
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            gameRunning = false;
        }
    }

    SDL_BlitSurface(bitmap, &source, screen, &destination);

    SDL_Flip(screen);
}
```

When the window is loaded it turns black and the image wont appear. What's wrong?

Comment: You can look at the return-value of `SDL_BlitSurface` to see if it's successful or not. http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlblitsurface.html

Comment: it returns -1. What does it means?

Comment: @WilhelmMichaelsen Did you read the documentation posted by PureW?

Answer (score 0):

You code is fine.

Did you check if `SDL_Surface* bitmap = SDL_LoadBMP("bat.bmp");` is returning a proper address? 
It will return NULL on failure to load the image.

There might also be a problem with SDL_Surface `screen` but that is not shown in the code.

Comment: this is the screen: `SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, SDL_SWSURFACE);`

Comment: And the window things are constants with 640 and 480 as value